# window.print on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to print an HTML page on IE7 but it only prints 1 out of 3 pages. I prints fine on Firefox and IE8. Is there a bug on IE7?

Here is the code:

`Click <a href="#" onclick="window.print();">here</a> to print this page.`

Comment: you may need to reformat your code to display properly - it's not showing up right now.

Comment: Can you expand on your definition of "pages" please?

Comment: Obvious question: When you click your print link, do you get the Print dialog box? If so, does the Print Range value default to 'All' ?

Comment: Yes. Everything appears to be "All" by default. It works fine on IE8, not sure why it's just IE7

Comment: Yeah, it's just an html page that is printer friendly (stripped from the graphics). But it's still an html page. Just a very slimmed down one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with IE7 only. If you clear all your floats before each DIV and inside your print.css make the position property as static for all the DIVs.